# Ajax submit form via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I have a working form which uses FormData.  I have now realised that this does not work in IE8 or IE9.  Therefore, I am trying to create an alternative submit for these browsers.  So in my submitHandler, I have the following

```
submitHandler: function (form) {
    if(typeof window.FormData === 'undefined' ){
        ie_ajax_upload();
    }
    else {
        //normal form submit
    }
}
```

So if the browser does not support FormData I call the function ie_ajax_upload.  At the moment, this function looks like the following

```
function ie_ajax_upload(){
    var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none"></iframe>');

    $("body").append(iframe);

    var form = $('#my-form');
    form.attr("action", "php/process.php");
    form.attr("method", "post");

    form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
    form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

    form.attr("target", "postiframe");
    form.attr("file", $('#fileOne').val());
    form.submit();

    return false;
}
```

## fileOne is the id of my file field in my form.  At the moment, with the above, the function is successfully called.  However, IE8 is giving the error

> Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

In relation to form.submit();

Why would this be occurring?

Thanks

Comment: I always used http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ when submitting multipart forms in unsupporting browsers, works great.

Comment: You are setting a file attribute on the form tag which in my eyes is not supported. Aren't you suppose to add a input file element to the form and submit?

Comment: I tried using that form plugin but could not get it working alongside the JQuery validate plugin.  In regards to adding an input file element, not to sure, I will have a look now.  Thanks